# flutter how to make google play and upstore subscriptions in conjunction with the backend

Tags: flutter, backend, payment, revenuecat

there is a backend in my application, there is a request to get user data. How do I connect subscriptions so as to synchronize with the backend, so that in this request conditionally comes:
{
'name': 'NAME',
'subscriptions': '7-days',
}

I have already subscribed through revenue cat, but after looking at the responses of other users, I did not find an answer for myself